# \sfrac breaks vertical spacing in multlined enviroment

Tags: spacing, mathtools, multline, xfrac

I have found that including a `\sfrac` from the package `xfrac` into a `multlined` environment from `mathtools` completely breaks the vertical spacing of the `multlined`. Actually, this affect the spacing between the first and second line, for all the `multlined` blocks in a gather.

This is particularly bad since it result in a negative spacing with overlapping text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
  \texttt{multlined} (two copies inside \texttt{gather}) works fine
  \begin{gather}
    \begin{multlined}
       \sin(x) = \sum_i \frac{(-1)^i x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!} \\
       = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040} \\
       = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040}
    \end{multlined} \\
    \begin{multlined}
       \cos(x) = \sum_i \frac{(-1)^i x^{2i}}{(2i)!}  \\
       = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720} \\
       = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720}
    \end{multlined}
  \end{gather}
  but with even a single \texttt{\textbackslash sfrac} breaks the spacing
  \begin{gather}
    \begin{multlined}
       \sin(x) = \sum_i \frac{(-1)^i x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!} \\
       = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040} \\
       = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \sfrac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040}
    \end{multlined} \\
    \begin{multlined}
       \cos(x) = \sum_i \frac{(-1)^i x^{2i}}{(2i)!}  \\
       = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720} \\
       = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720}
    \end{multlined}
  \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

This happens only with `multlined`. Nothing strange happens if I use `split` inside `gather` or a `multline`.

Comment: It might be related to the `\substack` error, but I see no difference in the lengths being used. Also the `\substack` problem was due to `\math@cr@@` and `\sfrac` does not seem to be messing with that (AFAICS)

Comment: @daleif You are right, my question has to do with vertical spacings, differently from the `\substack` error.

Comment: no idea why this happens

Comment: In any case, I'm not a fan of multine or multlined, and prefer align, for example combined with `\MoveEqLeft`, I feel that gives a more consistent look than this moving left and right of the first and last line and the rest centered

Comment: It is very strange that it affects both multlined. If you copy the last gather and paste it after the current one, and remove the `\sfrac`, the problem does not bleed into the extra gather. I

Answer (score 3):

Not so much a fix as a workaround...put in in its own box prior to entering `gather`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}
  \sbox\mybox{$\displaystyle\sfrac{x^5}{120}$}
  \begin{gather}
    \begin{multlined}
       \sin(x) = \sum_i \frac{(-1)^i x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!} \\
       = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{5040} \\
       = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \usebox{\mybox} - \frac{x^7}{5040}
    \end{multlined} \\
    \begin{multlined}
       \cos(x) = \sum_i \frac{(-1)^i x^{2i}}{(2i)!}  \\
       = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720} \\
       = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720}
    \end{multlined}
  \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]